# query_posts worked when wp_query didn't -- trying to understand (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, loops

This is an odd question, in that I've already found a working solution. But: I'd really like to understand why it worked, and why what *seemed* like it should have, didn't. If you can explain why I'm an idiot, I'll be grateful.

The task:  modify the main loop to exclude a category, and only show two posts per page.

Here's what worked:

```
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    query_posts("cat=-17,-18&posts_per_page=2&paged=$paged");
    ?>
```

Here's what didn't:

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-17', 'posts_per_page=2' ); ?>
```

Nor did this:

```
 <?php $query = array (
  'cat' => -17,
  'posts_per_page' => 2
    );
  $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
?>
```

So: What's going on here?

Many thanks,

-m

Comment: Maybe this helps: [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why it doesn't work:

1) `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-17', 'posts_per_page=2' );` didn't work because you're attempting to pass 2 arguments. It needs to look like this, if you're doing a string query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-17&posts_per_page=2' );
```

2) Your second query is correct, but the reason why it's "not working" is more than likely your subsequent loop - which you've left out of your code. When you're using query_posts, you're modifying the global $wp_query object, so your loop can just look like this:

```
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    //Do stuff....
endwhile;endif;
```

But using a new instance of WP_Query it needs to look different. Here's your fixed code:

```
<?php
$query = array (
    'cat' => -17,
    'posts_per_page' => 2
);
$queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
if($queryObject->have_posts()) : while($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post();
    //Do stuff....
endwhile;endif;
```

More on WP_Query here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: One more thing: If you're excluding multiple categories, use category__not_in. `'category__not_in'=>array(17, 18)`